# Ahow to run single matlab code for multiple images

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a matlab code. I want to execute on set of images.
Anybody can help me,running the code for multiple images?

Thanks All.

A simple code is like halftoning  on a number of images.

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;
a=imread('lena-y.png');
inImg = double(a);
[row,col] = size(inImg);
b=zeros(row,col);
error = 0;
for i = 1: row
       for j = 1 : col      
           outImg(i,j) =255*(inImg(i,j)>=123.6);

           error = (inImg(i,j)-outImg(i,j));
           if(j < col)
                inImg(i,j+1) =  (inImg(i,j+1) + (5/16*error)); 
           end;

           if(i < row && j >1 )
               inImg(i+1,j-1) = (inImg(i+1,j-1) + (3/16 *error));
           end;
           if(i<row)
               inImg(i+1,j) = (inImg(i+1,j) + (7/16 *error));
           end;
           if(j < col && i < row)
               inImg(i+1,j+1) = (inImg(i+1,j+1) + (1/16 *error));
           end;
       end;
end;
```

Comment: provide the code you have, you probably just need to put it into a loop.

Comment: how can run above code for some numbers of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your code block as a `function`. Save it into a file called halftone.m:

```
function result = halftone(I)
    inImg = double(I);
    [row,col] = size(inImg);
    ...
    ...
end
```

This allows you to call this function on any number of images, so you can just read them in and call it easily in a different script:

```
a=imread('lena-y.png');
result_a = halftone(a);
b=imread('another-image.png');
result_b = halftone(b);
```

See this tutorial for more on scripts, functions, and writing programs in matlab: http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/writing-a-matlab-program-69023.html